# Short story identification: girl addresses school in the face of genetic-engineering health-scare

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, genetic-engineering

An earlier, unanswered, question has had me scratching my head trying to remember the author and title of particular short story.

In the background revealed in the story, there is a health scare amongst the parents of a school. Children have received genetic modification intended to be improving. The change has an unexpected defect, causing  the eldest of the enhanced children have started to spontaneously fit and (it is implied) die. If I remember correctly, the epileptic fitting is referred to as 'blitzing',

The story itself is presented as a a first-person address by a girl, one of the few without the modification, to her school appealing for calm and understanding.

I must have read this in the early nineties, but the anthology it was in could have been published any time in the previous 15 years. I had thought it was by Asimov, but I've looked through all of the collected works and can't find it, so I suspect it was perhaps an anthology that he edited.

Comment: Re-opened because neither this question nor the one marked as a duplicate have an accepted answer although it's almost certainly the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

The story you are looking for is "Sisters" by Greg Bear, which you can find in "Tangents" (a short story collection).

It's a freaking awesome story!

Comment: How does that story specifically match what the OP asked?

Comment: There's a similar story with a very different ending. In this other story, which I've lost track of, it turns out at the end that the "normal" girl either engineered the defect or had discovered it and deliberately kepy quiet about it, letting all the "perfect" kids get sick and die.

Comment: A free EBook copy can be found at http://www.baen.com/Chapters/ERBAEN0036/ERBAEN0036.htm. It does use the term "blitz" and the symptoms are described as similar to a *grand  mal* seizure.